# A question about Service and Client

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29).
I found that in my client cpp file there's a code line

```
 beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts srv
```

and

if (client.call(srv))

So I think the server function received data from client by “srv”.

But in my server cpp file， it says

```
ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", add);
```

and

```
`bool add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
       beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response &res)`{}
```

so it looks like server function received two variables（one for request one for response）.

My question is that if I wrrite it

```
`bool add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts srv)`{}
```

will it work?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372026/a-question-about-service-and-client/) by [sunpansiyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70268/sunpansiyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The line

```
beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts srv;
```

Is actually declaring a service message, which is defined [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) as:

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

A service message, by convention is split into a "request" and "response" part. For this message "a" and "b" are part of the request and "sum" is part of the response. To access these variables in code you can do like:

```
 beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts srv;
 srv.request.a = 5;
 srv.request.b = 4;
```

Your service, defined by:

```
ros::ServiceServer service = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints", add);
```

Has a "callback" function, here named "add" whose signature by design explicitly names the the request AND response parts. That is why "add" takes two arguments.

```
bool add(beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Request  &req,
               beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts::Response &res)
```

For practical purposes however all you have to do to call the service is declare the client:

```
ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<beginner_tutorials::AddTwoInts>("add_two_ints");
```

And then call it with the SINGLE argument, srv:

```
 client.call(srv)
```

And after the call, it it was successful, you can access the result like this:

```
srv.response.sum
```

Does that help answer your question at all?

Cheers, JB

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2021-02-24**:
@sunpansiyu any update on this?

**Comment by [sunpansiyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70268/sunpansiyu/) on 2021-03-21**:
I am so sorry for my late response!
Thank you for your answer, it helps me a lot!

**Comment by [sunpansiyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70268/sunpansiyu/) on 2021-03-21**:
I understand it now ,thank you!